Does $\sum_{k = 0}^{qN} [e^{-\frac{\pi^2 k^2}{N}} - (\cos \frac{\pi k}{2 q N})^{8 q^2 N} ] \rightarrow 0$ as $q\rightarrow \infty$?
Let $N, q \in {\mathbb N}$. Let $S(N,q) = \sum_{k = 0}^{qN} [e^{-\frac{\pi^2 k^2}{N}} - (\cos \frac{\pi k}{2 q N})^{8 q^2 N} ] $.
$N$ is fixed. Does $S(q,N)$ tend to zero as $q$ tends to infinity? How does one prove it, if so?
This problem comes out of the investigation of the continuum limit of a model of a quantum mechanical particle on a ring of finitely many sites. The number of sites is $2qN$. $N$ should be large but the question can be posed for any $N$.

Yes, this is true (essentially by dominated convergence). Let's introduce $M=qN$. As $M\to\infty$, the two sums converge separately, the first one to $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-\pi^2 k^2/N}$. As for the second one, we have an inequality of the form $\cos x\le 1-\delta x^2$ for $0\le x\le \pi/2$. Moreover, $\log (1-a)\le -a$ for $0\le a<1$, by the concavity of $\log$. It follows that the second summand can be estimated by
$$
\cos^{8M^2/N}\frac{\pi k}{2M}\le \left( 1 - \frac{\delta k^2}{4M^2} \right)^{8M^2/N} \le e^{-2\delta k^2/N} .
$$
Thus, given $\epsilon >0$, we can find an $M_0$ such that $\sum_{k\ge M_0} | \ldots | <\epsilon$, for all $M$.
Since $\cos^{8M^2/N}\frac{\pi k}{2M}\to e^{-\pi^2k^2/N}$ as $M\to\infty$ for fixed $k$, the claim is now obvious.

Thank you Christian. Since $\cos x < e^{-x^2/2}$ for $0<x\le \pi/2$, the summands of the second sum are less than the summands of the first for $k>0$. But that doesn't make any difference to the proof.

This inequality would have simplified the argument a bit (when I estimate the second summands), if I had been aware of it.
